# Get data from custom tableView cell text field

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a tableView, a custom table view cell inside the tableView, and a few text fields inside the custom table view cell.

I update a class based on the information in the text fields that are in the table view cells.

I am able to use the didDeselectRowAt function to successfully get the data in the text fields of the cells to update my class, however, this is not the right implementation because it requires the user to click and deselect the cell that the text field is in and it would be better if the class was updated after the text field was edited. I've searched for a similar function of tableViews but did not find one that worked.

In my CustomTableViewCell class, I am also able to create a function that executes when editing of the text field ends, however this is in another class and I'm unsure how to populate my players class from this function.

Here is the code that is in the ViewController:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    for item in players {
        if item.uniqueRowID == indexPath.row {
            item.name = cell.textboxName.text!
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to do something similar to this, populating my 'players' class with the data from the text fields inside the custom tableview cells, but I would like it to happen when editing finishes in each text field, and this code does not work in the customTableViewCell class.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to create a delegation protocol from your cell back to your view controller

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, but how can I know which cell the info is coming from? (indexPath)

Comment: Have the cell pass `self` when it calls the delegate method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a model object that is passed to the cell? Within the cell, any updates can be made as the user interacts. The editing triggers for the object are kept within the cell and can take immediate effect.

Here's a contrived example.

```
final class UIViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

  var players: [Player] = [] // Players set by something in the view controller.

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell else { fatalError() }

    cell.player = players[indexPath.row]

    return cell
  }
}
```

In the cell itself:

```
final CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

  var player: Player!

  weak var textField: UITextField!

  func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    player.name = textField.text
  }
}
```

Following on from this you have the option to further abstract the relationship using a ViewModel.

Comment: No problem @VladBarash, that was a fun challenge to solve. :)

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm even when using Realm 